# Selective Indentation in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, indentation, auto-indent

Is there a way to tell VS2010 to automatically ident lines **just inside methods**? Since I usually have only one namespace/class per file, I feel all this indentation a waste of space.

If that was possible, my method commands below would start after 4 chars, not after 12. this way I would get +8 visible chars in my screen (I try break my lines after 100 chars)

[image: Indentation]

Comment: That's not possible.  Fwiw, it violates all commonly held norms for what indenting should look like.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it might help http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,ef519229-154d-4ab9-85a3-dc5c18079bd6.aspx